# отмена Cancel() в cancellationTokenSource

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть cancellationTokenSource, который я использую повторно в сервисе плеера. При остановке плеера я вызываю `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();`, но мне так же надо потом заново запустить плеер с нормальным значением cancellationToken, как это сделать? В нынешней ситуации я вызываю `Cancel()`, но дальше не могу вернуть token в обычное состояние

Comment: `CancellationTokenSource` невозможно вернуть назад в состояние «отмены нет». Создавайте каждый раз новый `CancellationTokenSource`, не используйте старый повторно. _Ваш К. О._

Comment: Спасибо, буду создавать новый

Comment: Оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CancellationTokenSource` невозможно вернуть назад в состояние «отмены нет».

Почему так сделали? Дело в том, что значение `IsCancellationRequested` в `CancellationToken` может быть считано позже, возможно, в другом потоке, и если бы было возможно отменить отмену, то наш код не понимал бы, отмена реально состоялась, или нет. Состояние «отмена реально была» нам приходилось бы хранить отдельно, а значению `IsCancellationRequested` нельзя было бы доверять.

Чтобы этого всего не было, было решено, что `CancellationTokenSource` и связанные с ним токены могут менять состояние только в одну сторону.

---

Просто создавайте каждый раз новый `CancellationTokenSource`, не используйте старый повторно.